# Can Shazam retain full strength even after sharing it with many people?

Tags: dc-extended-universe, shazam

After sharing powers with his friends Shazam (Billy Batson) still seemed to have all his powers in the movie. Was this the case? Does this mean he can share his powers and create heroes without losing his own?

Comment: I believe they have the power of the other mages (siblings of Shazam), that makes six including Billy, and the seventh mage must be the one the gave Black Adam his powers.

Comment: @Baku Okay. That makes sense. But so does that mean he had the power of 6 mages before and now only has the power of the mage Shazam ?

Comment: I don't know, he didn't look like he had all that power....

Answer (score 5):

Well first of all he broke the staff so he can't create any more "Shazams".

In the comics, sharing his power did not diminish his abilities until Jerry Ordway’s Power of Shazam series.

However, based on the fact that he seemed to be the same after sharing his powers on screen, I think it didn't diminish his abilities.